# In a lattice which is a Boolean algebra an ideal is prime iff it is maximal

Tags: boolean-algebra, lattice-orders, universal-algebra

I need to prove the following statement:

> In a Boolean algebra (a lattice with complement operation) an ideal is maximal if and only if it is prime.

For every distributive lattice we have the $\implies$. For the reverse direction I could have only figured out that the ideal generated by $x$ and $x'$ are comaximal. I know that Boolean algebras are equivalent to Boolean rings so I would find interesting also a translated answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $I$ is a prime ideal in a Boolean algebra $B$.  Note that for each $x\in B$, $x\wedge x'=0\in I$, so either $x$ or $x'$ in $I$.  Now suppose $I$ is strictly contained in an ideal $J$; say $x\in J\setminus I$.  Then since $x\not\in I$, $x'\in I$.  But then both $x$ and $x'$ are in $J$, so $x\vee x'=1\in J$.  Thus $J$ is not a proper ideal, which proves $I$ is maximal.